# retrieve value from mysql database to be used as value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, google-maps

I am making a map and I want to use the value from the database to be used as the coordinates in the javascript.  Please see below:

I want to change the default values of the longitude and latitude by fetching data fro the database but I don't know how.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"     t      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LatiPoint(options)
    {
        this.UserName = "";
        this.JobType = "";
        this.UserMood = "";
        this.Latitude = "";
        this.Longitude = "";
        this.Pic = "";
        this.Color = "red";
        this.OpenInfoWindowInitial = false;

        if (options != null)
        {
            this.UserName = options.UserName;
            this.JobType = options.JobType;
            this.UserMood = options.UserMood;
            this.Latitude = options.Latitude;
            this.Longitude = options.Longitude;
            this.Pic = options.Pic;
            this.Color = ( options.Color == null ? "red" : options.Color );
            this.OpenInfoWindowInitial = ( options.OpenInfoWindowInitial == null   ? false : options.OpenInfoWindowInitial );
        }
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var LatiPts = new Array();
        LatiPts[0] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Dukot',JobType:'Balulang Cagayan     De Oro',UserMood:'drinking beer',Latitude:8.4542363,Longitude:124.63189769999997,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWindowInitial:true,Pic:''});
        LatiPts[1] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Alot',JobType:'Cagayan De Oro',UserMood:'with classmates',Latitude:8.458353831903118,Longitude:124.63627706511227,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWindowInitial:true,});
        LatiPts[2] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Lindongan',JobType:'SM Cagayan De Oro',UserMood:'feeling bored',Latitude:8.456188949479728,Longitude:124.62177167875973,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWindowInitial:true,});
        LatiPts[3] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Galal',JobType:'Carmen Cagayan De Oro',UserMood:'beer',Latitude:8.467607505884205,Longitude:124.62271581633297,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWindowInitial:true,});
        LatiPts[4] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Belen',JobType:'Cagayan De Oro',UserMood:'beer',Latitude:8.46332028090713,Longitude:124.63537584288326,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWindowInitial:true,});


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var infoWindows = [];
        var markers = [];

        // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
        function createMarker(map, point, title, icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
            marker.setMap(map);
            marker.setPosition(point);
            marker.setTitle(title);
            marker.setIcon(icon)

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < infoWindows.length; i++)
                    infoWindows[i].setZIndex(0);

                infoWindows[marker.counter].setZIndex(1);
                infoWindows[marker.counter].open(marker.getMap(), marker);
            });            

            return marker;
        }

        function createInfoWindow(html)
        {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.setZIndex(0);        

            return infoWindow;
        }

        function initialize() {

            // Create the Google Map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(0,0));

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0; i < LatiPts.length; i++) {
                var lpt = LatiPts[i];
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lpt.Latitude, lpt.Longitude);
                var html = "<span style='font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt'>";

                html += "<span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold'>" + lpt.UserName + "</span><br />";
                html += lpt.UserMood.substring(0, 30) + "<br/>";
                html += lpt.JobType.substring(0, 30) + "<br/>";


                html += "</span>";

                var imgPath
                if(lpt.Pic != "") {
                    imgPath = lpt.Pic
                } else {
                    imgPath = "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/marker.png"
                }
                //alert("imgPath = " + imgPath + " Pic: " + lpt.Pic)
                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imgPath);
                //icon.shadowSize = GSize.ZERO;

                var infoWindow = createInfoWindow(html);
                infoWindow.open();

                var marker = createMarker(map, point, lpt.UserName, icon);
                marker.setZIndex(0);
                marker.counter = i;


            if (LatiPts[i].OpenInfoWindowInitial)
                {
                    infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
                }
                infoWindows.push(infoWindow);

                markers.push(marker);


                bounds.extend(point);

                            }

            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }

        function handleNoFlash(code)
        {
            if ( code == GStreetviewPanorama.ErrorValues.FLASH_UNAVAILABLE )
                alert( 'You need flash player to view the panorama.' );
        }

        function convertLatLngToString(latlng)
        {
            var hour = parseInt(latlng)
            var min = parseInt((latlng - hour) * 60)
            var second = (((latlng - hour) * 60) - min) * 60

            return (hour + "&deg; " + min + "&#39; " + second.toFixed(2) + "&#34; ");
        }

    //]]>
    </script>    

    <style type="text/css">
        /*give the body height:100% so that its child
        elements can have percentage heights*/

        body{ margin:0;padding:0;height:100% }

        div.fullscreen{
            display:block;


            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;


            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: inherit;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" class="fullscreen" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <div id="streetview" style="width: 650px; height: 400px; display: none;"></div>
    <noscript>
        <b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
    </noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your PHP code!

Comment: You say you are making a map but the code shows a function only. If you can complete the question with complete code, it will be easy to help you.

Comment: I tried to post all the code but it wont allow me to.  It says error.  Anyway to broaden my question.  I want to customize the value of the latitude and longitude as you can see on the last two lines of the code.  The value there is default as I set it.  What I want is to get a value from a database.  Any additional inputs in the database should be fetched and should make a loop to create new lines of similar code above (the last two lines).  I hope I make sense :)   Thanks!

Comment: Don't post **all** your code.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here you go, I pasted the whole code.  I hope it's clear now.  I  need your help guys  :)  PEACE!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    <?php /* read from database into variable $results*/ ?>
    this.UserName = "<?php echo $results; ?>";
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Faruk.  I will try this one.  :)

Comment: But if I fetch from my database using same page with the javascript.  People can see my login details right?  How am I going to solve this please?  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use something in JS, it will be visible to user, so don't mess with stuff in JS that are valuable. And no, it will not be visible to user, it will be parsed on server in page load time. User will only see this.UserName = "User007";

Comment: Okay.  Can you please show me the whole code on how to fetch data from my table.  What if I have multiple values for usernames? The outcome that I want is to create a marker on the map using the value from my database.  So multiple markers are expected  :)  Pls Help me :)

Comment: Read this: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers Multiple usernames are processed by while or for loop on returned rows of data. So you get them one by one and do as you please with them :)

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to do it in javascript  :(  Can I insert those fetch codes directly in this javascript file?

Comment: Just change file extension to .php. Php files can have HTML, JS or CSS code in them, no problem :)

Comment: Please show me an example.  I am very new to this.  The example you gave me is too broad for me.  Can you show me exactly how please?  Let's say I have a username in my database and I want to use it on my javascript code as a value for "this.UserName"   LatiPts[0] = new LatiPoint({UserName:'Dukot',JobType:'Balulang Cagayan De Oro',UserMood:'drinking beer',Latitude:8.4542363,Longitude:124.63189769999997,Color:'yellow',OpenInfoWin‌​dowInitial:true,Pic:''});